Can all linear functionals be expressed in terms of a pairing?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be linear spaces and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bilinear mapping. Often this is called a pairing. Now the weak topology is defined as the weakest topology to make all linear maps from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ continuous. In some books it says that the weak topology is the weakest topology that makes all $\langle \cdot, y \rangle:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $y\in Y$ continuous. This implies that all continuous functionals from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ have this form $\langle \cdot, y \rangle:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Why is this the case? The bilinear mapping $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ was chosen arbitrarily so why can we express all linear functionals from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ using this pairing?

This is not true.  The weak topology with respect to the pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the weakest topology that makes all $\langle \cdot, y \rangle$ continuous.  But there may well be other linear functionals on $X$ that are not of the form $\langle \cdot, y \rangle$ and are not continuous in this topology.

@RobertIsrael thank you for your comment! Now im confused: another definition of the weak topology is that it is the coarsest topology that makes ALL functionals from X to the reals continuous...

I.e. it is an initial topology

"In some books" - can you give an example of book that says that without saying what specific mapping we consider? In general, when we speak about weak topology, we already have some topology of $X$, and as $Y$ we take all linear functionals continuous in this topology.

but can we express all of these linear functionals in terms of a pairing?
